# How do I use the Python 3.7 packages with the Python 3.9 interpreter？

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

The system I'm using is MacOS Big Sur 11.2.1. After I used Homebrew to upgrade everything on the system, I automatically upgraded Python 3.7 to 3.9, which caused my previous installed Python 3.7 packages not to be found under Python 3.9. Can I use the Python 3.7 package with the Python 3.9 interpreter? If you can. How do you do that? By the way, I found all the packages I had installed under Python 3.7。

In addition, I will use the command `brew search python3@`, return results ***boost - Python3

Python@3.7  Python@3.8  Python@3.9 ✅***, and I will use the command `brew Search Python@3.7`, Did not find Python 3.7 in the path he suggested. It has all become Python 3.9

Comment: Or, can I switch between versions of the Python interpretation without deleting Python 3.9?

Comment: Reinstall the packages. You can get the list of your packages in Python 3.7 with `pip freeze` . Then feed this list to pip in Python 3.9.

Comment: *How do I use the Python 3.7 packages with the Python 3.9 interpreter?* Don't even try. You must re-install them inside the 3.9 installation. Any other way is a recipe for a disaster...

Answer (score 0):

type pip freeze with your old version of python, then, make a doc call t.txt, copy what your pip shown in it, then, save under code as a python file and run it on your new python, give it some time, it should work!

```
import os
try:
    with open("t.txt") as f:
        l = f.readlines()
    print(l)
    for i in l:
        os.system(f"pip install {i}")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
input()
```

Comment: You simply need to call `pip install -r requirements.txt` where requirements.txt contains the output dump from `pip freeze` (`pip freeze > requirements.txt`)